# What is the recommended Airbrake logger for Django, pybrake or airbrake-django?

Tags: django, airbrake

On the Airbrake docs page, https://airbrake.io/docs/installing-airbrake/installing-airbrake-in-a-django-app/, there is a link to https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake-django#manually-sending-errors-to-airbrake, described as "our official Github repo".

However, if you simply click "Python" on the main page (https://airbrake.io/docs/installing-airbrake/installing-airbrake-in-a-python-app/) an integration with `pybrake` is described, including a link for Django integration which is specific to `pybrake` (https://github.com/airbrake/pybrake#django-integration).

This seems a bit confusing. What is the recommended way to manually log errors with Airbrake in a Django project?

Answer (score 0):

According to Airbrake's tech support, `pybrake` is recommended for Python 3 (cf. https://airbrake.io/blog/airbrake-news/python-3-a-first-class-citizen).